# C++ vector push_back with pointer to function

Tags: c++, vector, function-pointers, std-function

I have a class `Foo` which contains a `vector` of `Bar`s:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void create();
    void callback();

    std::vector<Bar> mBars;
}
```

My `Bar` class contains this constructor:

```
class Bar
{
    Bar(const int x, const int y, std::function<void()> &callback);
}
```

My `Foo` class has a `create()` method that adds `Bar`s to the `mBars` vector:

```
void Foo::create()
{
    mBars.push_back({ 1224, 26, callback }); //ERROR!
}
```

How can I set the function pointer, using `std::function`? and also without creating a separate object and `push_back` into the vector? Like the line above, where I get the error:

```
E0304   no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=CV::Button, _Alloc=std::allocator<Bar>]" matches the argument list
```

Comment: You aren't taking a pointer of the function. Plus for a `std::function` you'd have to use `std::bind`.

Comment: As an aside, you might want to look into [`vector::emplace_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`callback` is a member function and needs `this` to work correctly (unless you make it static, of course).  You can use `std::bind` or a lambda function and then wrap it into a `std::function`.

```
void Foo::create()
{
    std::function<void()> fx1 = [this](){ callback(); };
    std::function<void()> fx2 = std::bind(&Foo::callback, this);
    //mBars.push_back({ 1224, 26, callback }); //ERROR!
    mBars.emplace_back(Bar{ 1224, 26, fx1 }); //ok
    mBars.emplace_back(Bar{ 1224, 26, fx2 }); //ok
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin. This is exactly what I need:)